# How do you build Flump?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, ant, sdk, air

I've installed all the dependencies mentioned in [these instructions](https://github.com/tconkling/flump#building) but I still can't get it to work. Obviously, I've also downloaded the Flump exporter and the Flump runtime.

The next step is:

> 1.Build the flump runtime
>
> ```
>   flump/runtime$ ant -Dairsdk.dir=/path/to/air maven-deploy
> ```

I've never used Flash / AIR SDK / Flex SDK / Ant so it might be trivial, but I'm not sure what it means. I tried running it in the command line (I'm using Windows) after I changed /path/to/air to the path of AIR SDK's directory.

I got this message:
'Flump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Does anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: I tried running only this command:

```
ant -Dairsdk.dir=/path/to/air maven-deploy
```

After navigating to the directory where Flump is located I get the following error:

> Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
>
> Build failed

The Flump download contains only 2 files: flump-runtime.swc and flump-exporter.air.

Do you have any idea what is wrong now?

---

Edit 2: I have downloaded the source files from [this page](https://github.com/tconkling/flump/releases/tag/1.5.0) and it does find the build.xml file but I think there is a problem with the source files of Flump (the build still fails in the command prompt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flump/runtime$` is an indication of the command prompt.  You'll need to navigate to the `runtime` subdirectory of wherever you downloaded flump and run:

`ant -Dairsdk.dir=/path/to/air maven-deploy`

Reading up on command-line norms and command prompts might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did what you said and it worked but I think there is a problem with Flump.